# log4j2 - rolling file appender - original file is still there

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I´m using the following log4j2.xml

```
 <RollingFile name="RollingInstitut}"
 fileName="logs/converter-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
 filePattern="logs/converter-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
 <Policies>
 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
 </Policies>
 <PatternLayout>
 <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t]  %m%n</Pattern>
 </PatternLayout>
 <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4">
 </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
 </RollingFile>
```

The timebased triggering plociy is working, and the backup ist also created. But the old logfile is still there, eg. I have
converter-01-19-2018-1.log.gz and converter-2018-01-19.log 
After 4 days both are deleted 
What do I have to change, that the old logfile is deleted

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `DefaultRolloverStrategy` you can specify which file to delete or based on which pattern.

For example, following configuration will delete files older than 4 days i.e. files which are modified before 4 days -

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    <Delete basePath="logs/" maxDepth="1">
        <IfLastModified age="4d" />
    </Delete>
</DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```